# Truffle migrate Error: PollingBlockTracker

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, smartcontracts, truffle, infura

I'm trying to deploy a contract on Avalanche Fuji testnet using Truffle. Here is my truffle config:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const mnemonic = process.env["MNEMONIC"];
const infuraUrl = process.env["INFURA_URL"]; //https://avalanche-fuji.infura.io/v3/...
 
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');

module.exports = {

  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*"
    },
    fuji: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, infuraUrl),
      network_id: "43113",
      gas: 5000000,
      networkCheckTimeout: 1000000,    
      timeoutBlocks: 200,
    }
  },
  ...
  }
};
```

When I run `truffle migrate --network fuji`, I get the following error:

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.

/Users/me/Projects/myProject/node_modules/eth-block-tracker/src/polling.js:51
        const newErr = new Error(`PollingBlockTracker - encountered an error while attempting to update latest block:\n${err.stack}`)
                       ^
Error: PollingBlockTracker - encountered an error while attempting to update latest block:
undefined
    at PollingBlockTracker._performSync (/Users/me/Projects/myProject/node_modules/eth-block-tracker/src/polling.js:51:24)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:540:9)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)
UnhandledRejections detected
Promise {
  <rejected> {
    code: -32603,
    message: 'Socket connection timeout',
    data: { originalError: [Object] }
  }
} {
  code: -32603,
  message: 'Socket connection timeout',
  data: { originalError: { code: 'ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT' } }
}
...
```

Some people mentioned its the internet speed but the internet speed at my place is very fast. Does anyone know what the issue is? Is it the Infuria API?

Answer (score 1):

There might be many reasons

- your `infuraUrl` is either `undefined` or you did not paste the correct url.
- it might be dns issue. try to change the dns provider
- your infura node might go down. Infura sometimes suffers from outage

Answer (score 0):

Just to follow up if anyone else is facing a similar issue. I tried creating another Infura API, double checked that my API endpoint is not `undefined`, double checked everything, but to no avail. Another part of the error message which I didnt include in the original post is:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../binaries/uws_darwin_arm64_115.node'
Require stack:
- /Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v20.2.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ganache/node_modules/@trufflesuite/uws-js-unofficial/src/uws.js
- /Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v20.2.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ganache/dist/node/core.js
- /Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v20.2.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/migrate.bundled.js
- /Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v20.2.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/original-require/index.js
- /Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v20.2.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js
Falling back to a NodeJS implementation; performance may be degraded.
```

I just ran the following and reinstalled Truffle and it resolved the error

```
nvm install --lts   
nvm use --lts
```

I was running `Node v20.2.0` and `Truffle v5.9.0` but doing the above changed them to `Node v18.16.0` and `Truffle v5.9.1` and it worked. Contract is successfully deployed :)